# Computed value not updating on changing text box value in knockout javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Kapil_B/vz3r0bs3/9/
```

In this fiddle I am trying to update the formattedPrice2 value on changing the rates in the textbox.I am able to get the updated price but the price1 is not getting updated value.

Can you please tell me the reason why the price1 value is not getting updated? That is why formattedPrice2 is not getting updated.

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.newLot, value: dropdownAValue, optionsText: 'type'"></select>
<table align="left">
    <thead>
        <tr align="left">
            <th width="10%">Pair</th>
            <th width="10%">Rate</th>
            <th width="10%">formattedPrice2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:curArray">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:  rate().pair"></td>
           <td> <input data-bind="value: myQuote, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    // Class to represent a row in the price calculation grid
    function PriceCalculation(rate, myQuote, newPairs, nl, currentlotvalue) {
        var self = this;
        self.rate = ko.observable(rate);
        self.newPairs = newPairs;
        self.nl = ko.observable(nl);
        self.myQuote = ko.observable(myQuote);
        self.currentlotvalue = currentlotvalue;

        self.leverage = self.rate().leverage;



        self.formattedPrice2 = ko.computed(function () {
            var cur = self.rate().pair;
            //var price = self.rate().price;
            var price = self.myQuote();

            var pip = 1;
            var lot1 = self.currentlotvalue;
            var JPlot = lot1 * 100;

            if (cur.indexOf("/USD") > -1) {
                pip = lot1;
            } else if (cur.indexOf("/JPY") > -1) {
                pip = JPlot / price;
            } else if (cur.indexOf("USD/") > -1) {
                pip = lot1 / price;
            } else {



                var base = cur.split("/")[0];
                var counter = cur.split("/")[1];

                for (var i = 0; i < self.newPairs.length; i++) {
                    var base1 = self.newPairs[i].pair.split("/")[0];
                    var counter1 = self.newPairs[i].pair.split("/")[1];

                    var price1 = self.newPairs[i].price;
                    alert(price1);

                    if (base1 == "USD") {
                        if ((self.newPairs[i].pair) == ("USD/" + counter)) {
                            pip = lot1 / price1;
                        }
                    } else if (counter1 == "USD") {
                        if ((self.newPairs[i].pair) == (counter + "/USD")) {
                            pip = lot1 * price1;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            //alert(pip? "$" + pip.toFixed(2): "None");
            return pip ? "$" + pip.toFixed(2) : "None";

        });





    }

    // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
    function ReservationsViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.curArray = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.rates = ko.observableArray([]);

        // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
        self.rates = [ {
            pair: "EUR/HUF",
            price: 318.815,
            leverage: "20:1*"
        }, {
            pair: "USD/HUF",
            price: 265.13,
            leverage: "20:1*"
        }, {
            pair: "XAG/USD",
            price: 15.734,
            leverage: "1:1*"
        }, {
            pair: "XAU/USD",
            price: 1184.43,
            leverage: "1:1*"
        }];

        self.newLot = [{
            type: "Micro",
            lotSize: 0.1
        }, {
            type: "Mini",
            lotSize: 1
        }, {
            type: "Standard",
            lotSize: 10
        }];

        self.newlots = ko.observableArray(self.newLot);

        self.dropdownAValue = ko.observable(self.newlots);

        var currentlotvalue = 0.1;
        self.dropdownAValue.subscribe(function () {
            if (self.dropdownAValue().type == "Micro") {
                //alert("Micro");
                currentlotvalue = 0.1;
            } else if (self.dropdownAValue().type == "Mini") {
                //alert("Mini");
                currentlotvalue = 1;
            } else if (self.dropdownAValue().type == "Standard") {
                //alert("Standard");
                currentlotvalue = 10;
            }

            var newItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.rates, function (item) {

                return new PriceCalculation(item, item.price, self.rates, self.newLot[0], currentlotvalue)
            });
            self.curArray(newItems);
        },this, "change");
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Comment: 1) You should post the JS code; questions shouldn't rely on information in a JSFiddle, and the computeds you're asking about specifically aren't even in the HTML snippet as far as I can see.

Comment: 2) Can you distill this down to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue you're seeing?  You have a ton of code here that can't possibly be related.

Comment: You've declared `var price1 = self.newPairs[i].price;` which is not an observable and otherwise remains unchanged from the values established in `self.rates`.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the computed you will find that the values are being recalculated.  It's just the values you generate don't appear to change within the 2 decimal places you format to

Comment: Robert values are getting recalculated because of the change in field "price" but "price1" is not getting updated.

Comment: Origineil can you please tell me how to make it observable?

Comment: Edit your original question to explain what the `else` block is doing or is supposed to do because I don't see why you would need to iterate through all of the data objects to set the `pip` value. The pip for pair `EUR/HUF` is being affected by those pairs containing `USD` which I wouldn't think is correct, so some clarification on the logic is needed.

Comment: Value against EUR/HUF should be recalculated if value of USD/HUF changes. To get the updated value of USD/HUF I am reiterating the array.